# Python - how to remove item from list by exact value, plus the next 2 items in the list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
list = [1, 2, 'unwanted', 3, 'green', 'tomato', 'unwanted', 'random', 45]
```

and I'm trying to remove all `'unwanted'` items, plus the next two items, whichever they are. What's the simplest way to doing so? I'm looking to do this through list comprehension, if possible.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Mitch. Asking on SO, apparently :)

Comment: @Mitch. I completely agree with you. I am pretty much giving this guy a couple of minutes to respond before voting to close as off topic.

Comment: @Mitch. Not at all. I was just making a joke, but it wasn't a very good one.

Comment: @Mitch: I've tried using a for loop with enumerate, but made a mess of it and am too embarrassed to post it on here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by checking if there is an `'unwanted'` at the current position or in any of the 2 *preceding* items in the list:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 'unwanted', 3, 'green', 'tomato', 'unwanted', 'random', 45]
>>> [item for idx, item in enumerate(lst) if 'unwanted' not in lst[max(0, idx-2): idx+1]]
[1, 2, 'tomato']
```

It's generally a bad idea to use a variable with the same name as a built-in function so I renamed it to `lst` here.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this will check the previous two items, not the next two.

Comment: Perhaps `[idx:min(idx+2, len(lst)]`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Exactly, because one wants to remove the `'unwanted'` and the next two items when an `'unwanted'` was found, so one has to check the "currently last" 3 items.

Comment: Crafty. I had forgotten about the unwanted at `idx`.

Comment: The list contains hundreds of items, and it's unlikely that it will have an 'unwanted' in the last 3

Comment: @StevenH Maybe the wording wasn't correct. This answer checks if the current item or any of the two preceeding items is `'unwanted'` and if so it will remove the item. It's not the last 3 items in the complete list.

Comment: It doesn't actually remove the items from the list when I try it?

Comment: @StevenH No, it creates a new list without the "removed" items. That's what a list comprehension does. To replace the original list just do: `lst[:] = [item for idx, item in enumerate(lst) if 'unwanted' not in lst[max(0, idx-2): idx+1]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
[element for ndx, element in enumerate(list) if (list[ndx] != 'unwanted') & (list[ndx-1] != 'unwanted') & (list[ndx-2] != 'unwanted')]
```

Comment: That will wrap around the list and give (probably) wrong results if an `unwanted` was in the last two places, i.e. `[1, 2, 'unwanted', 3, 'green', 'tomato', 'unwanted', 'random', 45, 'unwanted']`

Comment: It does not. I'm actually surprised that it works if unwanted is in the first two places

Comment: But it fails if it's in the last places: `list = [1, 2, 'unwanted']` combined with your comprehension gives an empty list.